# Xml Spring config: Unable to locate springframework.org/schema/security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security, xml-configuration

I have an xml config and when I try to import spring-security namespace it gives me 2 choices: `springframework.org/schema/p` and `springframework.org/schema/c`. What I need is: http://www.springframework.org/schema/security (which cannot be found). It is a spring boot project and I need to configure security with xml. I think I am missing some dependecy but i am not sure which one.

This is the xml config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
```

And build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0' 
  compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.5.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the spring security namespace link at the top of your xml file and you've an extra quote in the schema links on the bottom part. Try adding the following to the xml file exactly as it is below here:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">    
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir, I can't believe I missed something like that

Comment: No problem Lexy, glad I could help.